# How to register AuthSchemes on HttpClient

Tags: java

I have this code

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.getAuthSchemes().register("ntlm",new NTLMSchemeFactory());
```

However eclipse says that DefaultHttpClient is deprecated and I replaced this with

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
```

However now I  have no api called getAuthSchemes(). So Now with this new class, how do I register the auth scheme?

I also found

```
ArrayList<String> authPrefs = new ArrayList<String>(2);
authPrefs.add(AuthSchemes.KERBEROS);
client.getParams().setParameter(AuthPNames.PROXY_AUTH_PREF, authPrefs);
```

but here also getParams and AuthPNames are deprecated.

So what is the non-deprecated way of setting Authentication Schemes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configuration is not longer done in the client but in the request, after you have your `HttpPost` (or `HttpGet`, or whatever) and before calling `execute()` do this:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(...);

ArrayList<String> authPrefs = new ArrayList<String>();
authPrefs.add(AuthSchemes.NTLM);
authPrefs.add(AuthSchemes.KERBEROS);

// ...

RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setProxyPreferredAuthSchemes(authPrefs).build();
post.setConfig(config);

// ....

client.execute(post);
```

Comment: Why am I getting a "Could not find method org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost.setConfig" message in the Android Monitor?  I'm on htpclient-4.5.1 and httpcore-4.4.3. On some servers this doesn't affect the authorization, on others it crashes the app?

Answer (score 2):

To expand on morgano's answer, here is a quick deprecation conversion for those who are using **NTLMTransport** and **ksoap2** to authenticate in a Windows Authentication/NTLM environment (I'm using **httpclient-4.3.1**, and **httpcore-4.3** as dependancies, but other jars should work as long as they're >= 4.3).

Remove

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

Replace with

```
public static HttpPost httppost;
public static HttpClient client;
```

in your "call" method, replace any HttpPost and redefine your "client" **before you setHeaders**

```
//....
httppost = new HttpPost(url);
client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
ArrayList<String> authPrefs = new ArrayList<String>();
authPrefs.add(AuthSchemes.NTLM);
authPrefs.add(AuthSchemes.KERBEROS);
RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setProxyPreferredAuthSchemes(authPrefs).build();
httppost.setConfig(config);
//....
```

then in your setupNtlm method, remove getAuthSchemes

```
client.getAuthSchemes().register("ntlm",new NTLMSchemeFactory());
```

and add the authPrefs to your HttpGet (**key here is that the HttpPost and HttpGet needed to config the authPrefs before client.execute**)

```
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
ArrayList<String> authPrefs = new ArrayList<String>();
authPrefs.add(AuthSchemes.NTLM);
authPrefs.add(AuthSchemes.KERBEROS);
RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setProxyPreferredAuthSchemes(authPrefs).build();
httpget.setConfig(config);
```

It looks like there are still some deprecated functions like HttpEntity.consumeContent(), but the above changes worked for me when compiling for API 23.